# JBoss - Configuration – JSP see no CLASS files

Tags: jsp, jboss

I am sorry for probably trivial question.
I have following issue: after deploy of WAR file and JBoss running all project files automatically extracted in some folder in C:\jboss\server\default\tmp\deploy. But then browser enter some page it’s generated in C:\jboss\server\default\work\jboss.web\localhost[project]\org\apache\jsp
And JSP files see only CLASS files located in this folder. Mean, only in case I copy it manually to this folder. 
I think, I missed something in configuration. Please could you help?
-   How to make CLASS files reachable for JSP files without any manual intervention.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us what youve tried

Comment: I even do not know where to start with this issue.
The only thing I tried is to copy CLASS files manually, but in this case it looks like object classes loaded twice.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle them in the WAR. Seriously. Just put them into `WEB-INF/classes/`.

**Do not** tamper with `tmp/` after you have deployed the application, unless you want to keep crashing your application in many spectacular and colourful ways. The classes that you find around `tmp/` are usually compiled from JSPs on the fly and might be overwritten at a later point in time.

Also, they will probably have been loaded by some classloader already, and by replacing the on-disk copy, you are begging for trouble at a later point when some other module has to load that class, but it will get a different version.

Editing JSP is OK, but might need a bit of a tweaking in the `web` subsystem, most notably, adding the following snippet:

`<configuration>
  <jsp-configuration check-interval="3"/>
</configuration>`

You might want to change some other properties - look at the [online documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Web+subsystem+configuration) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, 
That was not this issue, but you help me to look at the problem from different point of view and it looks like resolved now.

Thanks again.